# selecting data from mysql database via a procedure using callable statement

Tags: java, mysql

I have created a simple procedure that will count the no. of rows from a table in mysql database. How do I use callable statement to print out the count from a java class ?

Comment: why do you need to write a stored procedure for just counting number of rows in a table ??, a simple select would suffice  :P

Comment: just trying to play with procedures and callable statement . My problem is how to get OUT parameters of the procedure from java file

Comment: are you able to return from the stored procedure ??

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have already made a connection to your database  and your procedure returns the count as varchar2 this should be enough

```
public void getCount() {

    Statement stmt = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;

    try {

        stmt = con.createStatement();


        //p_get_count should be replaced by your procedure name
        String s1 = "call p_get_count(?); end;";
        cstmt = (CallableStatement) con.prepareCall(s1);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.execute();
        String s2 = cstmt.getString(1);
        System.out.println(s2);
        cstmt.close();
        stmt.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: will OracleCallableSatement work for MySql Database ?

Comment: you can use CallableStatement from java.sql.CallableStatement   http://srikanthtechnologies.com/articles/j2ee/mysql5.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA or Hibernate as ORM then you can look for [NamedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html), it will help in attaining what you are trying to do.